# WPF checkbox programmatically remove event

Tags: wpf

Does anyone know how to programmatically remove/add the checked and unchecked event on WPF checkbox?

Comment: Are you using any design pattern such as MVVM as this may colour the answer?

Comment: yes.. using the MVVM.. how does it relate to remove/add the routed event anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your event handlers are proper methods and not anonymous delegates:

```
mycheckbox.Unchecked -= theEventHandler;
mycheckbox.Checked -= theOtherEventHandler;
```